# Print the following pattern for the given N number of rows

Tags: square

Pattern for N = 4
4444
4444
4444
4444

Sample Input 1:
7
Sample Output 1:
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777

my code is only print 4

Comment: int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int i=1;
    while(i<=n){
        int j=1;
        while(j<=n){
            cout<<"4";
            j++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        i++;   
    }

Answer (score 0):

Change `cout << "4"` to `cout << n`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    int n; 
    cin>>n; 
    int i=1; 
    while(i<=n){ 
        int j=1; 
        while(j<=n){ 
            cout<<n; 
            j++; 
        } 
    cout<<endl; 
    i++;
    }
}
```

Sample Input `7`, Output:

```
7
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
7777777
```